# Modules that need to be instantiated by Hilt must have a visible, empty constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, module, dagger, dagger-hilt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class WheelModule constructor(val size:Int) {

    @Provides
    fun provideWheel():Wheel = Wheel(size)

}
```

Modules that need to be instantiated by Hilt must have a visible, empty constructor.
[Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class WheelModule() {

 @Inject  val size: Int=0

    @Provides
    fun provideWheel():Wheel = Wheel(size)

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class WheelModule(val size: Int? = null) {

    @Provides
    fun provideWheel(): Wheel = Wheel(size)
}
```